# Swift: weird "snapping" search bar animation after cancel button selection using UISearchController?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have a weird issue, where upon searching SO, could not find anyone else experiencing this issue.

Basically I have a `UITableView` inside a `UIViewController`, which is embedded in a `UINavigationController`. I've set up a `UISearchController` above the `UITableView` with the appropriate `UISearchResultsUpdating` and `UISearchBarDelegate` functionality simply like so:

```
var sC = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
...
sC.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
sC.searchBar.placeholder = "Searching..."
sC.searchBar.delegate = self
sC.searchResultsUpdater = self    

table.tableHeaderView = sC.searchBar
```

The problem is that when the search bar is visible, and the Cancel button is initiated, the search bar will animate back in place, but right before it stops, it has this **snapping** animation.

This can be seen in the demo video link (animated gif doesn't clearly show the issue): [Search Bar Issue](https://vimeo.com/318692669)

If it is not expected behavior, how can I fix this so that the animation of the search bar is much more fluid instead of this **snapping** animation?

Thanks!